# Showing a message to the user if website does not open

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I'm trying to show a message to the user if the requested website does not open (or the internet is not working). The message I want to show is

> "Site is not working. Please contact the administrator."

How can I do this? Here's what I have

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        WebBrowser1.Navigate("google.com")

        Dim connectn As Boolean

        If connectn = False Then

            MsgBox("site not working please contact the developer")

        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Back_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Back.Click
        WebBrowser1.GoBack()

    End Sub

    Private Sub Forward_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Forward.Click
        WebBrowser1.GoForward()
    End Sub


    Private Sub Button4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        WebBrowser1.Stop()
    End Sub


    Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        WebBrowser1.GoHome()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button5_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
        WebBrowser1.Refresh()
    End Sub

    Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Label1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Label1.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub Label2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Label2.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub CloseToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CloseToolStripMenuItem.Click
        Application.Exit()

    End Sub

    Private Sub DateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DateTimePicker1.ValueChanged

    End Sub

    Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: It should already be quite obvious to the user that the browser won't complete, WebBrowser isn't shy about it.  If you really need to help then use a 40 second Timer.  Start it when you call Navigate(), stop it in the DocumentCompleted event handler.  If the Tick fires then the page didn't load in time.

Comment: how can i do it please give me code

Answer (score -2):

It's best not to use the DocumentCompleted event handler as it will fire when a frame is complete, not necessarily the entire webpage. Instead use the following:

```
 With WebBrowser1

 .Navigate("google.com")

    Do Until Not (.IsBusy)
        Application.DoEvents()
    Loop

    Do Until .ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
        Application.DoEvents()
    Loop


End With
```

Other than that, if it is for a specific site you can find what the correct URL is and simply compare the "endstate" URL when the Webbrowser has completely loaded. If you want it to be generalized for any website you can find most information from this link [about page event handling for navigation errors.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/4bd23c54-5adc-4e1d-b093-bec93877c902)

Comment: `Do Until Not`? What’s wrong with `While`? Also, you can just check `ReadyState` in `DocumentCompleted` anyways…

Comment: Why would you add an extra event trigger that is going to fire each time a frame is complete when you can embed the loop when the navigate method is invoked? Seems like a cumbersome solution after having degraded the use of Do Until Not.